# Regex: Express questionmarks function without using it

Tags: regex

Using the `?` operator, usually means, either this or nothing..

```
ba?b = bab,bb
```

How can you reproduce this function, by just using the `*` and the `|` operator?

For example you can express the `+` operator by:

```
a+ = aa*
```

I thought of something like this:

```
a? = (a| )
```

But you don't seem to be able to parse an empty field like this.

Comment: Just use an empty alternative - `(a|)` or `(?:a|)`

Comment: The reason you can't parse an empty field like that is because it's not empty, it's a literal space.

Answer (score -1):

`(a|)` == `a?`

In computer science theory, `?` is often left out for minimalism. To simulate it, you can use `|` against the empty string.